# Finding similarity between two words using wup_similarity() in python

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet

I am pretty new to word net in python. I am trying to match two words to find a similarity score using Wu-Palmer algorithm , as shown below:

```
synset1 = wn.synset("teacher.n.01") #wn is wordnet import
synset2 = wn.synset("boy.n.01")    
print(synset1.wup_similarity(synset2))
```

**Output: 0.6**

```
synset1 = wn.synset("animal.n.01") #wn is wordnet import
synset2 = wn.synset("boy.n.01")    
print(synset1.wup_similarity(synset2))
```

**Output: 0.75**

So according to Wu Palmer model, boy is closer to animal than a teacher. Does that mean that this algorithm is not the correct one to find the word similarity? Can you suggest any alternative for this problem.

Comment: @Ahmed No I think this is different problem, Here it is talking about synsets and missing synset from the synsets

Comment: "Does that mean that this algorithm is not the correct one to find the word similarity?" it depends what similarity you want. If you want wup similarity then it's the perfect algorithm. If you want something else, then you need to explain what is that else that you want...

Comment: @Julien: Thanks Julein, I am very new to this field, I understood your point. Can you give some algorithm name which will show correct result in this context (like teacher/boy should receive more score than teacher/animal because teacher and boy are humans.) ? Or can I use some other algorithm along with this to achieve my motive. Any pointers are helpful.

Comment: Asking for algo / library recommendation is considered off-topic, and I know nothing about this field anyway, sorry.